# Upgrade Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy) to 23.10 (Mantic) breaks network config: How to upgrade network config?

Tags: 22.04, systemd-networkd, 23.10

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy) release running on a virtual, remote server based on OpenVZ. I can only access the server via SSH. When I try to upgrade to 23.10 (Mantic), I am locked out of the server after the next reboot. After I booted the recovery system via my hoster WebUI and chroot'ed into the productive system, `journalctl` seemed to unveil that only the loopback device `lo` had been configured during the last boot of the upgraded, productive system. (This also explains why I couldn't login via SSH anymore.)

I have a "pure" systemd installation which uses `systemd-resolved` and `systemd-networkd.service`. In Jammy, all these daemons were part of the package `systemd`. In Mantic, `resolvectl` seems to have moved into its own packages `systemd-resolved` and the upgrade procedure seems to have missed the package. But even after I additionally installed that package in the chroot'ed enviroment, the upgraded system is still not working.

This is the configuration of the old (working) system based on Ubuntu Jammy:

```
root@myhost:~ # ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/void 

root@myhost:~ # ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/void 
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet w.x.y.z/32 brd 85.215.93.43 scope global venet0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx:yyyy:zzzz:wwww:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz:wwww/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@myhost:~ # ip route show
default dev venet0 scope link
```

(Note, I replaced the globally routable IP addresses by placeholders due to privacy concerns.)

```
root@myhost:/etc # cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This configuration file is auto-generated.
# WARNING: Do not edit this file, otherwise your changes will be lost.
# Please edit template /etc/network/interfaces.template instead.

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Auto generated venet0 interfaces
auto venet0
iface venet0 inet static
        address 127.0.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        broadcast 0.0.0.0
        up route add default dev venet0
auto venet0:0
iface venet0:0 inet static
        address w.x.y.z
        netmask 255.255.255.255


iface venet0 inet6 static
        address xxxx:yyyy:zzzz:wwww:xxxx:yyyy:wwww:zzzz/128
        up ip -6 r a default dev venet0
```

Note, even though the file above contains the comment that the content is auto-generated, this is the only place where the IP addresses are configured. (I ran a recursive `grep` inside `/etc`.) Personally, I have never touched this file it was part of the initial installation/configuration done by my hoster. There is also no `interfaces.template`. Maybe this is part of the problem?

```
root@h2917298:/etc # ls -lh /etc/systemd/network/
total 0


root@h2917298:/etc/systemd # cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf 
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the resolved.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf' to display the full config.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
DNS=81.169.163.106 85.214.7.22
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=my-domain.tld my-second-domain.tld
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

How do I transform that configuration for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy) into a configuration for 23.10 (Mantic) such that it still works after the upgrade?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has an upgrade path (*currently*) to Ubuntu 23.04, but no further. You mention direct upgrade to 23.10 which is currently only supported via re-install; thus you should have this issue; so please clarify what you mean by '*upgrade*' since the [Ubuntu tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) doesn't do what you are asking about.

Comment: I replaced the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and ran an `aptitude update` followed by an `aptitude full-upgrade`.